# MercadoPago Test user

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm struggling to create some test users for the button.

Following these instructions

[Create test users](https://developers.mercadopago.com/documentation/create-test-users)

This code is supposed to be used to get the tests users, but i have no idea where to use that, or how, and the documentation is kinda poor

```
Request - Curl

curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
'https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/test_user?access_token=your_access_token' \
-d '{"site_id":"MLA"}'
```

The website is made in PHP

Any bit of  advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `curl` used from the command line you can change this to a php file assuming that curl is enabled.

```
<?php

// add your access token
$access_token = "your_access_token";
$data = array('site_id' => 'MLA');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/test_user?access_token=$access_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// json response    
echo $response;
```

you can convert the json $response to an array using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and process the data

sample output

```
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "nickname": "TT123456",
    "password": "qatest123456",
    "site_status": "active",
    "email": "test@test.com"
}
```